# Sybase ODBC driver for Microsoft Access on Windows 7 64bit

Tags: ms-access, odbc, sybase

I am looking for a Sybase ODBC driver for Micosoft Access on Windows 7 64bit. Where i can download it?

Comment: You would only need the x64 bit driver if you are using Access x64. The default and recommend version of Access is to use the x32 bit version on windows x64. I would double check you are in fact using Access x64, since in most cases you are using x32 and thus should be using x32 ODBC drivers - even when using Sybase x64.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to register to download, but [this is one 64-bit Windows ODBC driver for Sybase](http://download.openlinksw.com/downwiz/login.vsp?prod=odbc-sybase-mt&os=x86_64-generic-win-64&os2=x86_64-generic-win-64&release-dbms=6.0-syb15&pform=3&pfam=1&pcat=1).

Comment: That's my employer's site, but not the best pointer...  We make a few [ODBC drivers for Sybase](http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-sybase/).  There are a few [deployment options for the described requirement](http://download.openlinksw.com/solwiz/wizard.php?uda_step1_radio=1&client_application=1&client_language=1&client_interface=3&client_opsys_family=1&client_opsys=x86_64-generic-win-64&client_32_on_64=64&server_dbms_family=4&server_dbms=syb10&server_opsys_family=9999&server_opsys=other&enterprise_level=0&dbms_server_install=2)...